# Remove dead code from executable

Tags: c, gcc, ld

I am aiming at removing as much dead code as possible from my executable to reduce code-size. I followed a number of tips from some other questions on Stack Overflow and am using `-fdata-sections -ffunction-sections... + ...--gc-sections` in my makefile. However I have one question.

I am first compiling all my `.o`'s using `-fdata-sections -ffunction-sections` as flags. Then I am archiving these into a static library (`lib.a`). Then I am building the executable linking this `lib.a` and using the `--gc-sections` flag in this linker. However this doesnt seem to do any improvement. Is this because I am archiving first? Does archiving remove the effect of splitting into sections? (Also, any form of "strip" I am using doesn't seem to affect the executable *at all*!)

Comment: If your library is already properly factored into `.o` files, this should have minimal or no benefit. The only way it helps is if your library is made up of huge `.o` files that contain lots of functions, some of which are unused in the program.

Comment: Yes, each of the .o files do contain considerable amount of functions, with a lot of unused functions. Still the reduction obtained is very small. Will it be more effective if I do NOT archive these .o's before linking them?

Comment: It is unlikely that the archiving or not-archiving of the `.o` files will make any difference to the executable. The most effective way to achieve reduction is to create smaller object files, containing only groups of functions that are always used together. That way, if an object file that originally contained 8 callable functions is split into 8 (or more) separate object files, and your program only calls 1 of the 8 callable functions, then only that 1 function and its support code will be linked. This can leave internal functions exposed; make sure your internal names are systematic too.

Comment: Thanks for the comment... Also, is there a quick way to identify a function that is not used anywhere in the code but appears in the executable?

Comment: With very recent GCC (4.6 doesn't work reliably; 4.7 acceptable, 4.8 better), try compiling everything with `-O2 -flto` and then linking with `-O2 -flto -fwhole-program`.  You may also find that installing the new "gold" linker helps.

Comment: You are aware that using -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections... + ...--gc-sections will also increase your code size, possibly to the effect that it outweighs the removal of dead code? Since you force each symbol in its own section, the compiler can't use a short jump instruction but must use long jumps everywhere.